# Replace value using lookup in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like below

```
col1  col2  col3
1      A     23
2      B     20
3      A     23
4      B     0
5      B     20
6      A     0
7      C     10
```

I want to replace all `0` by the values of col3 when col2 matches. For example in this case `row4, col3` should be replaced by `20` and  `row6,col3` should be replaced by `23`

EDIT:
since `row6,col2` is `A` I want the most frequent non zero value or unique non zero value(in this case 23) of `col3` corresponding to `col2==A`

Comment: why 23 for `row6, col3`? How does it relate to the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has clarified that he wants to replace any zero values in `col3` by the most frequent non-zero value for each `col2` group.

As the question is tagged `data.table` here are some `data.table` solutions:

#### 1. update in join with `ifelse()`

```
library(data.table)
# find most frequent non-zero value by group
tmp <- DT[col3 != 0, .N, by = .(col2, col3)][order(N), .(col3 = last(col3)), by = col2]
tmp
```

> ```
>    col2 col3
> 1:    C   10
> 2:    A   23
> 3:    B   20
> ```

```
# update on join
DT[tmp, on = .(col2), col3 := ifelse(col3 == 0, i.col3, col3)][]
```

> ```
>    col1 col2 col3
> 1:    1    A   23
> 2:    2    B   20
> 3:    3    A   23
> 4:    4    B   20
> 5:    5    B   20
> 6:    6    A   23
> 7:    7    C   10
> ```

#### 2. update in join without `ifelse()`

There is a variant which replaces the `ifelse()` expression by a more sophisticated join:

```
tmp <- DT[col3 != 0, .N, by = .(col2, col3)][order(N), last(col3), by = col2][, col3 := 0]
tmp
```

> ```
>    col2 V1 col3
> 1:    C 10    0
> 2:    A 23    0
> 3:    B 20    0
> ```

```
DT[tmp, on = .(col2, col3), col3 := V1][]
```

> ```
>    col1 col2 col3
> 1:    1    A   23
> 2:    2    B   20
> 3:    3    A   23
> 4:    4    B   20
> 5:    5    B   20
> 6:    6    A   23
> 7:    7    C   10
> ```

#### 3. Using `zoo::na.aggregate()` and `raster::modal()`

The `zoo` package offers several functions for replacing `NA` values.

```
DT[col3 == 0, col3 := NA][
  # replace NA by modal value (most frequent value) per group
  , col3 := as.integer(zoo::na.aggregate(col3, FUN = raster::modal)), by = col2][]
```

> ```
>    col1 col2 col3
> 1:    1    A   23
> 2:    2    B   20
> 3:    3    A   23
> 4:    4    B   20
> 5:    5    B   20
> 6:    6    A   23
> 7:    7    C   10
> ```

Note that this solution may return different results from the first two solutions in edge cases:

- If a `col2` group contains only zero values in `col3` so there is no most frequent non-zero value for that group. Then these zero values are returned as `NA` while the other two solutions leave them unchanged.
- In case of ties within a group, i.e., there are two or more values in `col3` which occur equally frequent, it is not defined which one to prefer over the other.

Answer (score 1):

By using `zoo` `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
df$col3[df$col3==0]=NA # 1st replace 0 to NA
df=df[order(df$col2,df$col3),] #order df
df$col3=na.locf(df$col3)    
df[order(df$col1),]
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    A   23
2    2    B   20
3    3    A   23
4    4    B   20
5    5    B   20
6    6    A   23
7    7    C   10
```

Or by using `dplyr` :

```
df%>%group_by(col2)%>%mutate(col3=ifelse(col3==0,unique(col3[col3!=0]),col3))
```